# Tried to register widget with id==buttonNode but that id is already registered

Tags: javascript, dojo

```
    <script>

require(["dojo/dom", "dojo/dom-construct", "dojo/on", "dojo/domReady!"], function(dom, domConstruct, on) {
             domConstruct.empty(dom.byId("buttonNode"));
        });

    var count=1;
    function change() {
        if(count == 1) {
        require(["dojo/ready", "dijit/form/Button", "dojo/dom"], function(ready, Button, dom){
        ready(function(){
            var myButton = new Button({
                label: "Count 1",
                onClick: function(){
                    count++;
                    change();
                }
            }, "buttonNode");
        });
    });
        } else if(count ==2) {
            require(["dojo/ready", "dijit/form/Button", "dojo/dom"], function(ready, Button, dom){
                ready(function(){
                    var myButton = new Button({
                        label: "Count 2",
                        onClick: function(){
                            count++;
                            change();
                        }
                    }, "buttonNode");
                });
            });
        }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body class="claro" onload="change()">
        <button id="buttonNode" type="button" onclick="change()"></button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

while clicking button its showing Tried to register widget with id==buttonNode but that id is already registered but i am deleting old button before creating new button using  domConstruct.empty.
 I tried both domConstruct.empty("buttonNode");
domConstruct.empty(dom.byId("buttonNode"));

I want different buttons for different login users like send request, cancel request etc. so i am checking condition and creating new button. The problem is if button already created with that Id i unable to replace button please help me.

Comment: Not related to this issue in particular, but could you please, please refactor your code?

Answer (score 2):

I think thats better to work with already created widget in registry than remove it and create it again:

```
    } else if(count ==2) {
        require(["dojo/ready", "dijit/form/Button", "dojo/dom", "dijit/registry"], function(ready, Button, dom, registry){
            ready(function(){
                var myButton = registry.byId("buttonNode");
                if (myButton) {
                    myButton.setLabel("Count 2");
                } else {
                    myButton = new Button({
                        label: "Count 2",
                        onClick: function(){
                            count++;
                            change();
                        }
                    }, "buttonNode");
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am more familiar with Dojo 1.6 than 1.7+, but definitely in 1.6 you need to remove a widget from the registry first.

Therefore I think you need to use **dijit/registry** rather than **dojo/dom-construct**.

```
require(["dojo/dom", "dijit/registry", "dojo/on", "dojo/domReady!"], function(dom, registry, on) {
    registry.remove(dom.byId("buttonNode"));
});
```

Comment: No Will Hawker, Tried to register widget with id==buttonNode but that id is already registered